# Runtime error embedding Javascript call in ASPX page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to get a basic webpage up and running that displays the video for my tests I create using SauceLabs. To do this, they provide a service to embed the video in Javascript.

I am creating the web page in ASP in Visual Studio 2010. However, I'm getting an error when I navigate to my page.

My ASP page looks as follows and simply takes in a jobID (jID) and an access code (code) which are fed into the JavaScript call.

```
   <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Show Video.aspx.cs" Inherits="ResultsDisplay.Show_Video" %>

   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head runat="server">
       <title>Test Video</title>
       <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://saucelabs.com/video-embed/<%=jID%>.js?auth=<%=code%>">
       </script>
   </head>
   <body>
       <form id="form1" runat="server">
       <div>
           <div id="flowerrorbox"></div>
           <a
                href="."
                style="display:block;height:450px"
                id="player">
           </a>
       </div>
       </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```

However, when I access the page, Visual Studio throws an error (in a dynamic script block) as follows:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'flowplayer' is undefined

Although I can ignore the error, nothing appears on my webpage.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Gordon

Comment: Are you including the flowplayer JavaScript in your own source? Have you looked at the HTTP request/response with a debugging tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some JavaScript code trying to use a variable named `flowplayer` somewhere and the variable has not been defined. Can you paste the rendered source from the `script` tag in your browser's address bar and get the code back? Have you tried reloading the page with `Ctrl-F5`? Does the script assume that there is a variable named `flowplayer` already defined when the page loads? These are a few debugging questions you might want to look into.

Comment: Thanks Dave - being something of a Javascript beginner, I didn't realise that the script I was calling from SauceLabs didn't contain EVERYTHING. I have now loaded another script containing "flowplayer" in my HEAD section and it now works!